# Export sqlite DB to csv issue

Tags: csv, sqlite, export

When I used `db.execSQL(.mode csv)` in Java code, it generates error in logcat.

```
/AndroidRuntime( 1363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
/AndroidRuntime( 1363): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: .mode csv
```

but if I issue the same in sqlite console, it works. I also cannot set separator in java code.

```
sqlite> .mode csv
.mode csv
sqlite> .separator ,
.separator ,
sqlite>
```

Can anyone share experience with me or what is correct approach ? I will be appreciated if codes are provided.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The `.mode csv` syntax and other dot-commands are proper to the sqlite shell, which is a specific program built on SQLite.

What you can do in java is just use the Database engine, not the `.mode`, `.help`, `.quit` or `.separator` from another program.

However you can find the source code for the SQLite shell here.

```
fossil clone http://www.sqlite.org/src _my_sqlite_repository
mkdir SQLite_source
cd SQLite_source
fossil open ../_my_sqlite_repository
```

Then you can download the latest updates with `fossil update trunk` and see the source code at `src/shell.c`. You will probably notice that this is the only piece of source code around that includes additional libraries.